# JS trigger another element by class after click on a button

Tags: javascript, html

If i click on a button, i want to trigger another button selected by class.

I wrote the following HTML:

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4").click()">Click</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array,so invoke `click` will not work

Comment: You wrote that code and what happened?

Comment: Nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment `document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4")` will return an array,thus `document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4").click()` will not work

you need to get the element rather than array

So change

```
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4").click()">Click</button>
```

to

```
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4")[0].click()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Or [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which is in theory faster as it doesn't need to search the entire DOM as it can exit early as soon as it finds the first match, unlike `getElementsByClassName` which searches the entire DOM

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah,but OP needs to clarity his question with more details

Answer (score 0):

[`Document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) has the suffix `getElements` not `getElement` indicating that it's a collection/array

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s).

Use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("frame-16nsqo4")[0].click()
```

or better use

```
document.querySelector(".frame-16nsqo4").click()
```